# Compare character in string (which is modified by "=" Operator)

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to use `isLarger()` to compare two string integer and return true if `a` is larger than `b`.

If I input 31232 (inputString="31232") in `main()`, `getPalindrome()` convert it to 31213 (changedString="31213"), but `isLarger(changedString,inputString)` turns out to be true consistently.

But if i input 12345 (converted to 12321), it turns out false consistently.

I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding of C++ or logical oversight in my code but I cannot figure out. I guess the problem maybe from the comparison itself or `output[lg-1-i]=input[i];` in `getPalindrome()` and I tried to replace it with `output.replace(lg-1-i,1,1,input[i]);` but no luck.

Can anyone help figure out what the problem is? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Compare if the string integer, return true if a > b
bool isLarger(string a, string b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length()) return a.length() > b.length();
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.length();i++) if (a[i] > b[i]) return true;
    return false;
}

//Copy LHS of the string to RHS
string getPalindrome(string input) {
    string output=input;
    int lg = input.length();
    int half_lg = (int)lg/2;
    for (int i=0;i<half_lg;i++) {
        output[lg-1-i]=input[i];
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    string inputString;
    cin >> inputString;
    string changedString = getPalindrome(inputString);
    if (isLarger(changedString,inputString))
        cout << changedString<< "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

===========

Thank you all for helping me. I am new in C++, and sorry for asking such dumb question. To anyone curious. The code i write for : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

Comment: Anything wrong with `changedString > inputString`?

Comment: @Manu343726: I wouldn't call it well done. The correct way to traverse things in C++ is with iterators!

Comment: Why are you implementing your own comparison for `std::string` when it has perfectly good set of comparison operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your `isLarger` function is incorrect. For equal length strings it returns true if **any** character in `a` is greater than the equivalent character in `b`.

I'd suggest an improvement but I'm not really sure what your intention is. I just know you haven't captured it in the code you've written.

Comment: It does explain the problem: `a=44446` and `b=55555` will return **true**, and it shouldn't.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Duh, I'm too tired to offer good advice (or read simple English).

Comment: @MarceloCantos you're too tired. *I'm too tired.* I just realized this is supposed to be on a palindrome and its originating non-synthesis, which my samples it *not* reflective of. duh.

Answer (score 1):

As john suggested, isLarger returns if **any** character in a is larger than the equivalent in b. You could simply use `a > b` which does the job.
In case you want to practice, here is the correct method:

```
//Compare if the string integer, return true if a > b
bool isLarger(string a, string b)
{
  if (a.length() != b.length()) 
    return a.length() > b.length();
  for(size_t i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
  {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) 
      return true;
    else if(a[i] < b[i])
      return false;
  }
  return false; //strings are equal.
}
```

Comment: The strings are the same length, and the characters will compare correctly as said-strings. Simply returning (a > b) will suffice.

Comment: Why complicate things so much when a simple `return a > b` will do?

Comment: @juanchopanza *exactly*.

Comment: Added the `a > b` suggestion. Just telling the Author "use a > b" does not help him understand why his original code does not work or how `a > b` or `a.compare(b)` works.